# How to remove shipping method before rate calculation?

Tags: php, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

A client has a woocommerce store with special shipping requirements. Some products can only be shipped with some shipping methods.

I have written custom code to remove rates based upon product criteria. I am using the `woocommerce_package_rates` filter to loop through the `$rates` and `$package` and then selectively remove certain rates based on product meta. However, this filter occurs AFTER ALL the rates have already been fetched via external APIs. This is not performant.

**Is there a way to remove rates or entire methods based on product shipping class or meta BEFORE the rates are calculated?**

Comment: With questions like this it can be interesting to look for the [hook in the source code of WooCommerce](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/b19500728b4b292562afb65eb3a0c0f50d5859de/includes/class-wc-shipping.php#L362), so you can see what code precedes it before the hook in question is executed. Regards

Comment: You should create a function on your functions.php and add_action woocommerce_package_rates and manage your shipping and package calculation accordingly.

Comment: @RajeevSingh I am currently using that method. However, that filter seems to be applied AFTER rates have already been retrieved / calculated. I want to prevent them from being calculated in the first place to increase performance.

Comment: @7uc1f3r Good tip. I've looked over the source already. There are a couple of nearby hooks, but I'm not quite sure how to go about using them to access the shipping methods before rates are calculated.